# problem with baking high poly to low poly model

Tags: texture-baking

okay, so i'm trying to bake a normal map of a sculpted cracked stone wall on a low poly one. but when I do. it like scatters everything around, and give random weird colors other than your typical blues and purples, its putting out like yellow, green, and red.

[image]
this is what the low poly looks like.

[image]
this is the high poly.

[image]
and this is what the normal map looks like when baked.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong, or if there is a way to fix this.
all I know is I can't render this without baking to the low poly.
so if you guys know what to do. and how to help. please let me know.

this is what the baked image looks like[image]

Comment: Anything with a blue<0.5-- your yellows-- is where the the low poly failed to enclose the high poly.  Increase ray extrusion or use a cage.  Or, possibly, where your high poly has backwards normals, but that shouldn't be the case.  Anything purple is probably just hitting something close to a 90 degree angle: use a low poly that better defines the high poly, avoid 90 degree bends in the high.  But also, don't judge a normal map on the image.  Judge it on how it looks on the mesh when used as a normal map.

Comment: this is what I see when I use the baked image. /Users/nielsen2022349/Desktop/Screen Shot 2022-01-18 at 10.55.31 AM.png

Comment: We can't see the image because it's not a valid link and the image is on your desktop. You need to edit your question and upload the image there with the image icon of the toolbar.

Comment: okay, that is done

Comment: Thanks. Have you tried to increase the *Extrusion* value as suggested and checked the face orientation?

Comment: As Nathan says, try with a cage, otherwise it's often tricky...